# VMWare Guest to Host-Webserver (nginx) connection doesn't work

Tags: networking, vmware, nginx

How do I debug the following situation: I have Nginx, php etc. installed on a Mac, everything works perfectly.

However when I want to connect to it from inside a VMWare Windows 7 host, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` (in Chrome). IE doesn't work either.

`telnet <host-ip> 8080`

This gives me a blank screen, where I can't see what I'm typing. There are no errors or accesses logged by Nginx.

Comment: Why port 8080?, is it the port you have nginx working on or there is a proxy in between?. First disable the Mac's firewall to discard it as the cause

Comment: nginx runs on 8080, no proxy. Firewall is already disabled, i wouldn't be able to connect via telnet if it weren't.

Comment: Check that you don't have NGINX configured to run on localhost (127.0.0.1). If it works locally, you can reach one machine from the other and you don't have a firewall in between blocking port 8080 it has to work unless you have an IP issue.

Comment: It had to do with the NAT somehow, when I changed to bridge-networking it worked. Probably a VMWare/Windows-IP Bug.